# Counter-Intuitive Wilcoxon Output

Tags: paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have three sets of measurements of the same samples - one 'reference' case, and two 'test' cases (Test 1 and Test 2). The residuals are non-parametric, so I am comparing each test case to the reference using a Wilcoxon test. I'm using a paired test because my ultimate goal is to find out which test case is most similar to the reference case.

**My problem:**

[image: The problem]

In this figure, the Test 1 points are clearly more scattered around the 1:1 line than the Test 2 points. However, the output of my Wilcoxon tests are:

```
# Using scipy.stats.wilcoxon; Python 3.6; Scipy 0.19
Test1 
 > WilcoxonResult(statistic=285.0, pvalue=5.9323660222401397e-06)
Test2
 > WilcoxonResult(statistic=874.0, pvalue=0.93382948582928071)
```

This suggests that Test 1 (more points on the 1:1 line) is highly significantly different from the reference case, while Test 2 (more points away from the 1:1 line) is indistinguishable from the test case. This seems counter-intuitive.

Could anyone enlighten me as to why this might be? I suspect that Wilcoxon is inappropriate for this application, but I'm not sure why, as it's sold as a 'non-parametric paired t-test'... is there an alternative test that might describe the patterns in my data?

Comment: If you want to compare two measurement systems have you considered using Bland and Altman plots? There are some threads on this site [tag:bland-altman-plot] which may help.

Comment: What are nonparametric residuals?

Comment: Fair question. Expect I'm getting my terms mixed up... I'm not a statistician. "The residuals are not normally distributed", is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wilcoxon rank sum test is not about scatter, it compares the ranks of the observations. The Test 1 points are very often above the reference points, so they ranks are structurally larger, i.e. the chance that the score of a randomly drawn sample is greater in the Test 1 group than in the reference group is significantly larger than 50%. This gets picked up by the paired Wilcoxon rank sum test. The Test 2 results are about as often above as below the reference, so their ranks are not significantly larger, hence the large P-value: this outcome is very likely if Test 2 results are on average not larger than reference samples.

If you want a conclusion in terms of the mean, then you could just do a paired t-test and rely on the central limit theorem, or check if the location shift assumption holds.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I'd clearly been misunderstanding how the Wilcoxon worked. Any suggestions for tests that might capture the increased variability in Test 1?

Comment: Levene's test for inequality of variances. Or fit a regression model with different variances for the error term and compare with a model with equal variances.